# Javascript passing object from include file to page

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, instance

I have created a javascript object and a function to build a new instance of the object. I now need to use this object on my page but am not having any luck, I feel that I am missing something.

**JS Include File**

```
function MyObject() {
    this.ID = 0;
    this.Name = "";
}

function GetObject(param1, param2) {
    //ajax call to get json string
    $.ajax({ //leaving out details this part works
    success: function(data) {
        var jsonData = $.parseJSON(data.d);

        var myObj = new MyObject();
        myObj.ID = jsonData[0].ID;
        myObj.Name = jsonData[0].Name;

        return myObj;
    });
}
```

This call works fine, however when I try to access the data on the page I get `undefined`

**Page**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var o = GetObject(1, 2);
    });
</script>
```

I was able to get it to work by passing a DOM object through to the function and assigning it there.

```
function GetObject(param1, param2, domObj) {
    //ajax call to get json string
    $.ajax({ //leaving out details this part works
    success: function(data) {
        var jsonData = $.parseJSON(data.d);

        var myObj = new MyObject();
        myObj.ID = jsonData[0].ID;
        myObj.Name = jsonData[0].Name;

        domObj.text(myObj);
    });
}
```

However this doesn't work for my application as I'm pull a lot of objects and would like to just reference them on the page. What am I missing? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could add a callback parameter to `GetObject()`, and call it in the `$.ajax` success callback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just resign your `GetObject` like this:

```
function GetObject(param1, param2, callback) {
    //ajax call to get json string
    $.ajax({ //leaving out details this part works
    success: function(data) {
        var jsonData = $.parseJSON(data.d);

        var myObj = new MyObject();
        myObj.ID = jsonData[0].ID;
        myObj.Name = jsonData[0].Name;

        // pass myObj via callback function parameter
        return callback( myObj );
    });
}
```

Now call it like:

```
$(function() {
     var  o = {};
     GetObject(1, 2, function(response) {
         o = response;
     });
});
```

As, within `GetObject` there is an ***AJAX*** request *(asynchronous process)* and object returned after ajax `success` function execute, so you need to take the help of `callback` function.

Comment: +1 for beating me to it :)  Also worth noting that this is necessary because ajax is asynchronous, so GetObject returns before the ajax call is done. Also, calling `return` inside of the success callback just returns from that anonymous function, not the surrounding GetObject function

Comment: <del>With doing it this way will I be able to use the object with dot notation to reference the properties? `o.Name` or would it be `o["Name"]`?</del> I was able to do so setting it as a new object `var = new MyObject();` Thanks!